# Is there joinWithSeparator for attributed strings

Tags: swift

Array of strings can be joined together with specific separator using joinWithSeparator method.

```
let st = [ "apple", "pie", "potato" ]
st.joinWithSeparator(", ")
```

As a result we will have "apple, pie, potato".

What if I have attributed strings inside my array? Is there easy way to combine them into one big attributed string?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Swift 5**:

```
import Foundation

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == NSAttributedString {
    func joined(with separator: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString {
        return self.reduce(NSMutableAttributedString()) {
            (r, e) in
            if r.length > 0 {
                r.append(separator)
            }
            r.append(e)
            return r
        }
    }

    func joined(with separator: String = "") -> NSAttributedString {
        return self.joined(with: NSAttributedString(string: separator))
    }
}
```

**Swift 4**:

```
import Foundation

extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: NSAttributedString {
    func joinWithSeparator(separator: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString {
        var isFirst = true
        return self.reduce(NSMutableAttributedString()) {
            (r, e) in
            if isFirst {
                isFirst = false
            } else {
                r.appendAttributedString(separator)
            }
            r.appendAttributedString(e)
            return r
        }
    }

    func joinWithSeparator(separator: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        return joinWithSeparator(NSAttributedString(string: separator))
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Awesome, possum. Thanks.

Comment: Worked like ice cream. Thanks!

Comment: By using reduce(into:_:) instead we can avoid having to return the attributted string

Comment: The attributed string equivalent of `["", "", "blah"].joined(separator: ",")` should give `",,blah"`. Seems like Swift 5 version above would give `"blah"`.

Answer (score 8):

Updated answer for **Swift 4**, together with some basic documentation, using Sequence:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: NSAttributedString {
    /// Returns a new attributed string by concatenating the elements of the sequence, adding the given separator between each element.
    /// - parameters:
    ///     - separator: A string to insert between each of the elements in this sequence. The default separator is an empty string.
    func joined(separator: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "")) -> NSAttributedString {
        var isFirst = true
        return self.reduce(NSMutableAttributedString()) {
            (r, e) in
            if isFirst {
                isFirst = false
            } else {
                r.append(separator)
            }
            r.append(e)
            return r
        }
    }

    /// Returns a new attributed string by concatenating the elements of the sequence, adding the given separator between each element.
    /// - parameters:
    ///     - separator: A string to insert between each of the elements in this sequence. The default separator is an empty string.
    func joined(separator: String = "") -> NSAttributedString {
        return joined(separator: NSAttributedString(string: separator))
    }
}
```

Comment: You can optimise it with `reduce(into:)`.

Comment: @RomanPodymov It doesn't make too much of a difference, since `NSAttibutedStrings` aren't copied on return. It does remove the extra `return` though.

Answer (score 7):

For **Swift 3.0**, Sequence type wasn't supported the I switch to Array. I also change the method name to use the swift 3.0 style

```
extension Array where Element: NSAttributedString {
    func joined(separator: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString {
        var isFirst = true
        return self.reduce(NSMutableAttributedString()) {
            (r, e) in
            if isFirst {
                isFirst = false
            } else {
                r.append(separator)
            }
            r.append(e)
            return r
        }
    }

    func joined(separator: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        return joined(separator: NSAttributedString(string: separator))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Took this solution from [SwifterSwift](https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift/blob/446c5886e5496a596ca107c26ab062af4239b2a0/Sources/SwifterSwift/Foundation/NSAttributedStringExtensions.swift), it's similar to the other ones:

```
public extension Array where Element: NSAttributedString {
    func joined(separator: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString {
        guard let firstElement = first else { return NSMutableAttributedString(string: "") }
        return dropFirst().reduce(into: NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: firstElement)) { result, element in
            result.append(separator)
            result.append(element)
        }
    }

    func joined(separator: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        guard let firstElement = first else { return NSMutableAttributedString(string: "") }
        let attributedStringSeparator = NSAttributedString(string: separator)
        return dropFirst().reduce(into: NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: firstElement)) { result, element in
            result.append(attributedStringSeparator)
            result.append(element)
        }
    }
}
```